# Get count of each unique value using ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What would the active record query be for the following SQL?

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(*) AS id FROM tags_mystories GROUP BY tag_id;
```

Thanks!

Comment: We are not a code translation service.

Comment: probably, but asking us to find software/services for you is also off-topic.

Comment: i assume snarky remarks is off topic too

Comment: Nope, those are free.

Comment: i dont understand why this isnt a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TagsMystory.pluck(:tag_id).group_by(:tag_id).count

Comment: Thanks. I got it working by swapping `pluck` for `select`

Comment: before this is locked for reasons i do not understand, and so as to be helpful: my final query was: `TagsMystory.select(:tag_id).group(:tag_id).order('count_tag_id desc').limit(10).count`